# Why we need to specify jar dependency in MANIFEST file

Tags: jar, websphere, manifest

When deploying an EJb jar as part of the EAR, i understand that the runtime jar dependencies of the EJb (i.e log4j) need to be specified in the EJB jar's MANIFEST.MF. But why is this? If I put the log4j in the same directory as the ejb jar, then it should automatically be included in the runtime classpath, no?

Why do i need to specify the log4j in the MANIFEST.MF again? On the same vein, what jars are automatically available to my EJB jar at runtime without having to specify them in MANIFEST? Just the jars shipped with  websphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify dependencies in manifest starting with Java EE 5. The location of libraries can be specified through `<library-directory>` element in application.xml. It defaults to `lib`.

Java EE 5 is supported by WAS 7.0 and higher.